# Call other class function before its own class in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, checkbox

I created a checkbox button with `class CheckBox`. I want to enable/disable `ResultTextField` according to the value of `checkbox ischecked`. So i linked a button with `@IBAction func retestRequestedCheckbox_onChange()`. The proble is the `func retestRequestedCheckbox_onChange()` is getting called before it updated value in `CheckBox` class. How can i update the checkbox value before calling `retestRequestedCheckbox_onChange()` function? Here is my code:

```
class Checkbox: UIButton {

    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked_checkBox") as UIImage?
    let unCheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkBox") as UIImage?
    var isChecked:Bool = false{
        didSet
        {
            if isChecked == true{
                self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }else {
                self.setImage(unCheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.isChecked = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton){
        if(sender == self){
            if isChecked == true {
                isChecked = false
            } else {
                isChecked = true
            }
        }
    }

}

 @IBAction func Checkbox_onChange(){


        if CheckboxButton.isChecked ?? false {
           ResultTextField.enabled = true

        } else {
          ResultTextField = false    
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply put the code for changing the UI in your `didSet` method?